# Multiple query datables code igniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, datatables

I would like to make a request on a table for each product line but I have to control if the product id is existing in another table, if so then I have to have two values ​​will cause can 'checked' or 'false'

in table product

```
id name
1  abc
2  def
3  ghi
```

in another table

```
  id id_product  id_catalogue
   1  2           1
   2  3           2
```

i need this result when ask width id_catalogue 1 for example

```
id produt  name    value     id_catalogue
 1          abc     false     null
 2          def     checked   1
 3          ghi     false     null
```

it must be in only one query

actually i have this, width my query who doesnt works nicelly

```
id produt  name    value     id_catalogue
 1          abc     false     null
 2          def     checked   1
 3          ghi     checked    null
```

thanks

```
$this->datatables->select("frs.raison_sociale as fournisseur,f.titre as famille,sf.titre as sous_famille,p.attribut as attribut,p.pa_centrale as prix_achat,p.marge_centrale as marge_centrale,p.pa_magasin as pa_magasin,p.marge_magasin as marge_magsin,p.prix_ht_public as public_ht,p.prix_ttc_public as public_ttc,p.id as id

                ,IF (cc.id_catalogue='".$id."', 'checked', FALSE) checked

                ",FALSE)
                    ->from('cat_produits p')
                    ->where('p.suppr','0')
                    ->join('fournisseurs frs','frs.id=p.id_fournisseur', 'left')
                    ->join('cat_familles f','f.id=p.id_famille', 'left')
                    ->join('cat_sous_familles sf','sf.id=p.id_sous_famille', 'left')
                    ->join('cat_cat_produits cc','cc.id_produit=p.id','left')
                    ->edit_column('id', '<input type="checkbox" name="produits[]" value="" id="ck_pdt_$1" class="check_ligne_pdt" $2>', 'id,checked');
```

**Edit :**  query works, i have two erros :

```
    missing cc.id_catalogue in select
```

and before :

```
     IF (cc.id_catalogue='".$id."', 'checked', '')  checked
```

after (missing as):

```
       IF (cc.id_catalogue='".$id."', 'checked', '') as checked
```

Comment: what do you mean by it does not work?

Comment: @tomexsans width my query i have all input check, because it exists with another id catalogue